# Moved JavaScript to a external file, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, external

Alright so, I'm new to java scripts, and have no knowledge what so ever with them, but I had this code right here:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#open").click(function () {
            $("#content").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });


$(function() {

        $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

        setInterval(function() { 
          $('#slideshow > div:first')
            .fadeOut(1000)
            .next()
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .end()
            .appendTo('#slideshow');
        },  8000);

    });

     $(document).ready(function(){
   if($("#copy").length == 0) {
       window.location.href = "http://landon.pro/copyright.htm;
   }
});
```

As a internal code with  tags around them, I wanted to move them to a external file, and once I did it all messed up.
If I removed the bottom code:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
   if($("#copy").length == 0) {
       window.location.href = "http://landon.pro/copyright.htm;
   }
});
```

It works just fine through a external file, can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? And how I can fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: most likely your issue is with the order you are including your files in your main HTML document.  This code relies upon jquery, are you loading your script file or the jquery file first?

Comment: also, you seem to be missing a closing Parenthasis

Comment: Your braces are oddly positioned, '$(function() {' .....'}); is enough to wrap all the document ready.  You have three.

Comment: What is the element with ID copy?